# Can a folder on Linux be belonged to multiple users?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, file-permissions

I have one folder on Ubuntu that can be read and written by user A and can be only read by user B. The solution I came up with is the following:

create a group which have read permission on this folder and two users: user A with read and write permission and user B with read permission but my question is a folder might be owned by two users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man: GETFACL(1), SETFACL(1):

- [setfacl(1): set file access control lists - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl)
- [getfacl(1): file access control lists - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getfacl)